# cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY - changing channel numbers

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to specify the channel numbers when using cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY. Does it support this? The work works by reading a path to an image resize it then filter and channel and then convert to grayscale. Many Thanks

```
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        path = self.files[idx]
        img = imread(filename=path)
        sample = resize(src=img, dsize=(1024, 1024))

        sample[:, :, 0] = 0
        sample[:, :, 1] = 0

        sample = cv2.cvtColor(sample, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cv2.COLOR_GBR2GRAY` is just a flag to convert the RGB image to a grey-scale.

```
from cv2 import COLOR_BGR2GRAY

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Output:

```
6
```

That means:

```
sample = cv2.cvtColor(sample, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

is same as

```
sample = cv2.cvtColor(sample, 6)
```

The answer is no.